# Rust API Design: Type parameters for optional values

Tags: generics, rust, api-design

I'm working on a Rust library that provides a trait which may optionally be implemented by a user. It can look like this:

```
pub trait MyHandler {
    fn do_something(&mut self);
}
```

The main struct in the library looks somewhat like this:

```
pub struct MyType<H: MyHandler {
    field_a: u8,
    field_b: u32,
    handler: Option<H>,
}
```

This works, but in reality a very small percentage of the users will implement a custom handler. The problem from an ergonomics point of view is that the type `H` will always need to be specified, even when no handler is passed in:

```
let t = MyType {
    field_a: 1,
    field_b: 3000,
    handler: None,
};
```

```
error[E0282]: type annotations needed for `MyType<H>`
  --> src/main.rs:12:13
   |
12 |     let t = MyType {
   |         -   ^^^^^^ cannot infer type for type parameter `H` declared on the struct `MyType`
   |         |
   |         consider giving `t` the explicit type `MyType<H>`, where the type parameter `H` is specified
```

All the library can do to simplify this, is to provide a dummy implementation that can be specified by the user:

```
pub struct DefaultHandler {}

impl MyHandler for DefaultHandler {
    fn do_something(&mut self) {}
}
```

```
let t = MyType::<DefaultHandler> {
    field_a: 1,
    field_b: 3000,
    handler: None,
};
```

Is there a good pattern to make this more ergonomic, without having to specify a dummy trait impl?

Comment: You can still use Dummy trait with hiding it from the api user, please check: https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=stable&mode=debug&edition=2018&gist=e0e3bdd76e057bb6b3bda640f22c4e77

Comment: Or you can use inner pattern to remove dummy trait and also option, please check: https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=stable&mode=debug&edition=2018&gist=9d260a87838bdce43026397fc30790ef

Answer (score 1):

Is there a difference between `None` and `Some(DefaultHandler)`?

If not, I would make `handler` of type `H`, and possibly require the user to specify `DefaultHandler` (instead of `None`).

Second, you could add a constructor function `new` that just creates a `MyType<DefaultHandler>` with `handler: DefaultHandler`, and you could - in addition to that and for callers that actually want a custom handler - add a constructor function `new_with_handler` that accepts a custom handler as an argument that is then used to create a `MyType` with the appropriate `handler`. (This is somewhat similar to e.g. `HashMap::new` (constructing a new `HashMap` with defaults) and `HashMap::with_hasher` (constructing a new `HashMap` with a given hasher).)

Comment: Yes, in my case there should be a difference between `None` and the default handler. The constructor function is a good idea though. HashMap is also a good reference in API design, I'll check it out!